# Codeigniter/PHP: Format db query as an array

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    $this->db->select('id, user_id')->from('be_users')->where('id',$user_id);
    $data['user_individual'] = $this->db->get();
```

If this is my db query, how do I get an array of one db row...

ie. I want to do something like `$data['user_individual']['id']->format_as_array`...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

CodeIgniter provides several methods to perform on query results.

See here: https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html

`result()` returns an array of PHP objects.

`row()` returns a single PHP object for that row.

`result_array()` returns an array of arrays.

`row_array()` returns a single array for that row.

`row()` and `row_array()` optionally take a parameter which is the number of the row you'd like to return.

Beyond this, it's difficult to tell exactly what you're asking for. You should be able to get your data out exactly as you like with these methods.

**Edit**:

Incidentally, the way to access these methods is through the query object returned from the `$this->db->get()` call:

```
$query = $this->db->get();

$rows = $query->result(); //array of objects
$rows_array = $query->result_array(); //array of arrays
$row = $query->row(); //single object
$row_array = $query->row_array(); //single array
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `$this->db->get();` you can use `$this->db->result();` which returns an arrayobject.

```
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');

foreach ($query->result() as $row)
{
    echo $row->title;
}
```

See: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html for details on how to obtain resultsets from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of $ this-> db-> get () use $ this-> db-> row_array ();

```
$this->db->select('id, user_id')->from('be_users')->where('id',$user_id);
$data['user_individual'] = $this->db->row_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

/**
 * format_database_array
 *
 * Lets you format the database object data to array

- @access  public
- @param   String $db_object : database query object
- @return  String            : Return array with data
  */

if ( ! function_exists('format_database_array'))
{

```
    function format_database_array($db_object)
{
    $db_array = array();

    if($db_object-> num_rows >0)
    {
        foreach ($db_object->result_array() as $row)
        {
            foreach ($row as $key => $value)
            {
                $db_array[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return $db_array;
}
```

}